# Packing symbols using scanLeft

Tags: list, scala, traversal, tail-recursion

[99 scala problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) has this question:

> > Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists.
> >         If a list contains repeated elements they should be placed in separate sublists.
> >
> > ```
> > Example:
> > ```
>
> ```
> scala> pack(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
> res0: List[List[Symbol]] = List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b), List('c, 'c), List('a, 'a), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
> ```

I have an understanding of the tail-recursive way to solve the above given problem. I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish the above using scanLeft where the intermediate result is the list of common elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `foldLeft`:

```
def pack[A](l:List[A]): List[List[A]] = l match {
  case head :: tail =>
    tail.foldLeft(List(List(head))) { (collector:List[List[A]], elem:A) =>
      if (collector.head.head == elem)
        (elem +: collector.head) +: collector.tail
      else
        List(elem) +: collector
    }.reverse
  case _ => List.empty
}
```

This only works for Lists.
A better solution would probably use `MultiSets`, although finding a Scala implementation is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

A concise but unoptimized version could look like this:

```
val l = List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)
for (i <-l.distinct) yield l.filter(_ == i)

res0: List[List[Symbol]] = List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b), List('c, 'c), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
```

Comment: Your result is not expected. The result should be List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b), List('c, 'c), List('a, 'a), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e, 'e))

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, `List` is now provided with the [`unfold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#unfold[A,S](init:S)(f:S=%3EOption[(A,S)]):CC[A]) builder which can be combined with [`List::span`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#span(p:A=%3EBoolean):(List[A],List[A])):

```
// val list = List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)
List.unfold(list) {
  case Nil  => None
  case rest => Some(rest.span(_ == rest.head))
}
// List[List[Symbol]] = List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b), List('c, 'c), List('a, 'a), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
```

or alternatively, coupled with `Scala 2.13`'s [`Option#unless`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) builder:

```
List.unfold(list) {
  rest => Option.unless(rest.isEmpty)(rest.span(_ == rest.head))
}
```

---

Details:

- Unfold uses an internal state which is initialized in our case with the `list` to split `List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)`
- At each iteration, we `span` that internal state in order to find the prefix containing the same symbol: `l.span(_ == l.head)` which is during the first iteration `l.span(_ == 'a)` and gives `(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a),List('b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e))`
- As `unfold` expects for each iteration an `Option` of a tuple whose first part is the new element to add to the list being built (here `List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a)`) and whose second part is the new value of the internal state (here `List('b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)`), that span fits exactly that requirement.
- We keep iterating the same step until the internal list is empty, in which case we tell the `unfold`ing we're finished by returning `None`.

Answer (score 0):

scanLeft is useful to calculate prefix sum, which is not the case in the problem. You may try to combine it with other calls, but I don't think it is the good way of solving the problem.

foldLeft seems to be more useful for this task.

```
def pack[T](list: Seq[T]) = list.foldLeft(new ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[T]])((ret, el) => {
    if (ret.isEmpty || ret.last.head != el)
      ret.append(new ArrayBuffer[T])
    ret.last.append(el)
    ret
  })
```

Two simple tasks was left for curious reader:

- Make it purely functional using List prepending
- Make the right return type

Answer (score 0):

No, `scanLeft` is not the appropriate method in this case. `scanLeft` will yield a collection of results with one element for each value in your list, plus the initial value you provide. So for example using `scanLeft` on `List(1,2,3,4)` will always yield a result with 5 elements

e.g.

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4).scanLeft(">"){case (last, x) => last + x}
res7: List[String] = List(>, >1, >12, >123, >1234)
```